# XCode 9 Color Set Crashing the App in iOS 10 before didFinishLaunching

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode9

The new Xcode 9 is having a nice feature - Color set. You can give custom colors for your app with names. You can then use these color sets in storyboards and in the code as well using `init?(named: String)` constructor of UiColor.

The problem is this will not work in iOS 10. This will immediately crash the with the message **libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**.

I tried to debug the app several times. But I finally realised that the issue is because of color sets which are not supported in iOS 10.

Can anybody let me know if there is any backward compatibility provided for this? Because, I want to use this feature as it is good to have custom named colors instead of arbitrary colors in palette.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same question, as the named color cannot be available on iOS 10, I wrote a shell with Python, it can replace the named color in both Storyboard and Xib when release the project.

http://artwalk.github.io/2017/10/23/Batch-replace-NamedColors-to-RGB-in-Storyboard/